# ajax php include не подключает файл?

Tags: php, ajax, include

Всем добрый день!

Есть некая форма, при изменении значений которой срабатывает `jquery` и отправляет `.ajax`-ом запрос в `php` файлик. в пхп файлике - строка которая ищет в `sql DB` нужные поля и выкидывает пользователю.

Проблема вот в чем:
Если в `php` файле, к которому обращается `ajax` прописать коннект до `DB` ручками - то все хорошо, если же просто прибить туда `include();` (или же `require_once();`) для файла в котором содержится коннект к `DB`, то ругается, выдает 500 ошибку, в связи с тем что переменная `$db` (в которой лежит коннект к БД) не определена. При этом ошибок о том что он не сумел подключить файл из `include();`  - нету.

Тоже самое если пытаюсь подключить файл с классами и вызвать потом этот класс. Ругается именно на то, что

> "Class 'ClassName' not found in ..."

Хотя ошибки о том, что не сумел подключить файл в котором лежит класс - нету.
Несколько раз специально задавал кривые пути и плохое название файла - тогда ругается, что такой файл не найден.

Comment: Если вы решили вопрос, отметьте один из ответов галочкой. Если вы не воспользовались при этом ни одним из тех, кто уже опубликованы, напишите свой и отметьте галочкой его.

Comment: @D-side а я делал правку, вероятно интернет протупил, сейчас сделаю еще раз.

Comment: Вы сделали правку, вставив решение в вопрос и пометку `[Решено]` в заголовок. Я эту правку откатил, как совершенно ненужную, и пояснил, почему ненужную.

Answer (score 1):

`include` и не будет ругаться, если настроено подавление некритичных ошибок, а вот `require` будет падать намертво, попробуйте именно его.

И не пишите круглые скобки для `require` и `include` - это не функции, а языковые конструкции, им не нужны скобки, они только запутывают вас.

Comment: `require` все так же не выдает фатальной ошибки.
даже спокойно выводит после себя `echo 'hey';` но стоит обратиться к классу который прописан в документе который подключаем через `require` - пишет, что такого класса - нет

Comment: вместо `'hey'` выведите на печать путь подключаемого файла и следом результат выполнения file_exists для него (то что сжирает require). + класс точно не имеет неймспейса? в проекте нет загрузчика типа композера?

Comment: Все, понял, я просто дурак и не так писал пути файла - надо было от `home` абсолютными писать..

Comment: плохая идея на счёт "писать от home". лучше от `__DIR__`. взаимное расположение файлов вы знаете и контролируете, а вот абсолютный путь до них от корня - нет. поэтому лучше `require __DIR_.'/../foo/bar/file.php'` и далее в том же духе. ещё лучше - один раз подключить файл с конфигом, в котором путь до корня проекта определён через `__DIR__` и сохранён в переменной или константе, а прочие файлы юзают уже это значение. и ещё лучше покурить маны в сторону автолоадера, и забыть про require вообще.